# VSCode c++ configuring for vc toolchain

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to start a work in vscode , latest C++ plugin version supports ms debugger, so as I'm mostly working under windows it was a signal to try this.

c++ tools plugin from MS and cmake tools were installed.

my test project was however not built . the problem is clear , but I need an advice from experienced vscode users how to solve this right.

cmake doesn't see vc compiler. 
(after using QtCreator) I expected that vscode could detect vc installation... however that's not so. ok, I have a two ways:

1. fill environment variables INCLUDE/LIB/PATH with a headers, libs and binaries
2. just run vcvarsall.bat x64

Second way is a simple and  reliable. so final question is:

how to run .bat at the begining of vscode start? 
(I don't mean write another bat/cmd, prepare the environment and run vscode inside the same script after that)

Comment: You noticed that VSCode is merely a code editor not an IDE?

Comment: yes :) how is this related with my question?

Comment: _"how is this related with my question?"_ Because VSCode is completely irrelevant for what you're asking IMO

Comment: mm, Microsoft added the support for C++ debuggers for primary platforms. it would be very oddly if vscode can be used in a debugger role but haven't an ability to build the app before. isn't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Where did you get the idea, that Visual Studio Code were just a barebones code editor? The official documentation for the [C/C++ for VS Code](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp) seems to disagree: *"Q: How do I build/run my project? - A: VS Code supports tasks that you can configure to build your application, and natively understands the output of MSBuild, CSC, and XBuild. For more information, see the [Tasks](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) documentation."* How to set up the build environment is a valid question, and VS Code is a relevant detail.

Comment: @IInspectable THX for enlightenment. May be my knowledge refers to way older versions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: What knowledge? Judging from recent comments you produced, there doesn't appear to be any noteworthy knowledge involved.

Comment: actually my question is more common than compiler config. - is there way to st up something other than preparing an environment outside of vscode and run just this after that?

Comment: @amigo421: [Tasks](http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) allow you to configure your build system, that doesn't involve changing the global configuration. If you are looking for a solution to set a global configuration, you should ask a different question.

Comment: user configuration is okay for me, just could not find how to trigger the event in a tasks. e.g. vscode starting

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is fairly old, I'll try to give a useful answer, in case others stumble across, just like I did.

I believe what you are trying to achieve is not possible. Code inherits the environment it was started with. If you did not launch it from a developer command prompt, you will not be able build and debug. (Building might be possible if every task first starts the vcvarsall.bat, but that slows things down by a lot. Debugging I think will still not work.)

If you are willing to, you can check out vector-of-bools [CMake Tools](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/index.html) extension which does build automation as well as automatic MSVC detection. It builds using CMake (thus you need to write your build scripts using CMake), but it will take care of building just by pressing F7, like what most VS users are familiar with.

Comment: yes, discussed this with a maintainers as well, and yes, using cmaketools mostly solves this. thank you.